# Splitting a string into elements creates a space that I can't remove

Tags: python, pandas, strip

I have a data frame with a column for 'genre' with strings like 'drama, comedy, action'.

I want to split the elements like this 'drama', 'comedy', 'action' so I've used;

```
Genre=[]

for genre_type in books['genre'].astype('str'):
    Genre.append(genre_type.split(','))
    
genre['genres_1']=genres_1
```

but, the result contains spaces between genres (other than the first one listed) like 'drama','_comedy','_action'. (I used an underscore to represent the space because otherwise it's hard to see).

so I tried

```
Genre_clean=[]
for x in books['genres_1'].astype('str'):
    Genre_clean.append(x.strip(' '))
Genre_clean
```

but the space remains, what am I doing wrong?

my full code is below;

```
import pandas as pd

# Creating sample dataframes
books = pd.DataFrame()
books['genre']=['drama, comedy, action', 'romance, sci-fi, drama','horror']

# Splitting genre
Genre=[]
for genre_type in books['genre'].astype('str'):
    Genre.append(genre_type.split(','))
    
books['genres_1']=Genre

# trying to remove the space
Genre_clean=[]
for x in books['genres_1'].astype('str'):
    Genre_clean.append(x.strip(' '))
Genre_clean
```

Comment: See my answer for a far better way to do this. As for what you're doing wrong, `strip` only removes spaces from the beginning and ends of strings, what you have after your first step is a string representation of a list (`books['genres_1'].astype('str')`), there aren't any outer spaces to remove from `"['romance', 'sci-fi', 'drama']"`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use traditional loops/list comprehension for pandas. Look up the equivalent, far more efficient, pandas specific function for whatever you want to do. Otherwise, there's no reason to use pandas.

See: [pandas str functions](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html#)

```
books = pd.DataFrame()
books['genre']=['drama, comedy, action', 'romance, sci-fi, drama','horror']

books.genre = books.genre.str.split(', ')
print(books)
```

Output:

```
                      genre
0   [drama, comedy, action]
1  [romance, sci-fi, drama]
2                  [horror]
```

---

If you want this as a string, you can join the list again with:

```
books.genre = books.genre.str.join(',')
    # Or, all at once:
# books.genre = books.genre.str.split(', ').str.join(',')
    # Or, just replace spaces with nothing:
# books.genre = books.genre.str.replace(' ', '')
print(books)

# Output:

                  genre
0   drama,comedy,action
1  romance,sci-fi,drama
2                horror
```